# How can I convert HTML to Object structure with text and formatting?

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, data-conversion, domparser

I need to convert a HTML String with nested Tags like this one:

```
const strHTML = "<p>Hello World</p><p>I am a text with <strong>bold</strong> word</p><p><strong>I am bold text with nested <em>italic</em> Word.</strong></p>"
```

Into the following Array of objects with this Structure:

```
const result = [{
  text: "Hello World",
  format: null
}, {
  text: "I am a text with",
  format: null
}, {
  text: "bold",
  format: ["strong"]
}, {
  text: " word",
  format: null
}, {
  text: "I am a text with nested",
  format: ["strong"]
}, {
  text: "italic",
  format: ["strong", "em"]
}, {
  text: "Word.",
  format: ["strong"]
}];
```

I managed the conversion with the DOMParser() as long as there are no nested Tags. I am not able to get it running with nested Tags, like in the last paragraph, so my whole paragraph is bold, but the word "italic" should be both bold and italic. I cannot get it running as a recursion.

Any help would be appreciated.

So the code I wrote so far is this one:

```
export interface Phrase {
    text: string;
    format: string | string[];
}

export class HTMLParser {

    public parse(text: string): void {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const sourceDocument = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
        this.parseChildren(sourceDocument.body.childNodes);

        // HERE SHOULD BE the result
        console.log("RESULT of CONVERSION", this.phrasesProcessed);
    }

    public phrasesProcessed: Phrase[] = [];

    private parseChildren(toParse: NodeListOf<ChildNode>) {
        this.phrasesProcessed = [];
        try {
            Array.from(toParse)
                .map(item => {
                    if (item.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && item instanceof HTMLElement) {
                        return Array.from(item.childNodes).map(child => ({ text: child.textContent, format: (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && child instanceof HTMLElement) ? child.tagName : null }));
                    } else {
                        return Array.from(item.childNodes).map(child => ({ text: child.textContent, format: null }));
                    }
                })
                .filter(line => line.length) // only non emtpy arrays
                .map(element => ([...element, { text: "\n", format: null }])) // add linebreak after each P
                .reduce((acc: (Phrase)[], val) => acc.concat(val), []) // flatten
                .forEach(
                    element => {
                        // console.log("ELEMENT", element);
                        this.phrasesProcessed.push(element);
                    }
                );
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Include the code that uses `DOMParser()`, need to see how you're doing what you claim to be doing so it can be fixed. ATM it really looks like you are asking us to write the whole code.

Comment: Why is "p" not included in `format`? What are your rules to include a tag in the `format` arrays?

Comment: Ok. Sorry it wasn't my intention to have youe write the whole code...

Comment: This data format doesn't make it clear which tags should be nested really. I would say you need to rethink that part first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recursion. And this seems a good case for a generator function. As it was not clear which tags should be retained in `format` (apparently, not `p`), I left this as a configuration to provide:

```js
const formatTags = new Set(["b", "big", "code", "del", "em", "i", "pre", "s", "small", "strike", "strong", "sub", "sup", "u"]);

function* iterLeafNodes(nodes, format=[]) {
    for (let node of nodes) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            yield ({text: node.nodeValue, format: format.length ? [...format] : null});
        } else {
            const tag = node.tagName.toLowerCase();
            yield* iterLeafNodes(node.childNodes, 
                                 formatTags.has(tag) ? format.concat(tag) : format);
        }
    }
}

// Example input
const strHTML = "<p>Hello World</p><p>I am a text with <strong>bold</strong> word</p><p><strong>I am bold text with nested <em>italic</em> Word.</strong></p>"
const nodes = new DOMParser().parseFromString(strHTML, 'text/html').body.childNodes;
let result = [...iterLeafNodes(nodes)];

console.log(result);
```

Note that this will still split the text when it is spread over multiple tags, which are considered non-formatting tags, like `span`.

Secondly, I'm not convinced that having `null` as a possible value for `format` is more useful then just an empty array `[]`, but anyway, the above produces `null` in that case.

#### Special case - insertion of `\n`

In comments you ask for the insertion of a line break after each `p` element.

The code below will generate that extra element. Here I also used `[]` instead of `null` for `format`:

```js
const formatTags = new Set(["b", "big", "code", "del", "em", "i", "pre", "s", "small", "strike", "strong", "sub", "sup", "u"]);

function* iterLeafNodes(nodes, format=[]) {
    for (let node of nodes) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            yield ({text: node.nodeValue, format: [...format]});
        } else {
            const tag = node.tagName.toLowerCase();
            yield* iterLeafNodes(node.childNodes, 
                                 formatTags.has(tag) ? format.concat(tag) : format);
            if (tag === "p") yield ({text: "\n", format: [...format]});
        }
    }
}

// Example input
const strHTML = "<p>Hello World</p><p>I am a text with <strong>bold</strong> word</p><p><strong>I am bold text with nested <em>italic</em> Word.</strong></p>"
const nodes = new DOMParser().parseFromString(strHTML, 'text/html').body.childNodes;
let result = [...iterLeafNodes(nodes)];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks !!!! a lot ! That absolutely made my day ! You're right an empty array is better than null in that case. However - how can i manage to add {text: "\n", format: null} after each "P" tag ?

Comment: That's what you would get if in the original HTML you would have that line break after each P tag. If not, then you need to explicitly make an exception for that case in the algorithm, which makes it less elegant.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks a lot. Just for the better understanding: how would I do this exception - this is not really clear to me where to hook in the algorythm . Sorry but I am kind of nooby here ....

Comment: Added a version to my answer that does this. Let me know if this suits your needs.

Comment: You're awesome ! Thanks a lot , you really made my day with this, Since I couldn't figure out how to implement this with recursion. Also that concept of generator function / yield is new to me - I definetly will dive deeper into this !

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively loop over the child nodes and construct the desired array using an array like `FORMAT_NODES`.

```js
const FORMAT_NODES = ["strong", "em"];

function getText(node, parents = [], res = []) {
  if (node.nodeName === "#text") {
    const text = node.textContent.trim();
    if (text) {
      const format = parents.filter((p) => FORMAT_NODES.includes(p));
      res.push({ text, format: format.length ? format : null });
    }
  } else {
    node.childNodes.forEach((node) =>
      getText(node, parents.concat(node.nodeName.toLowerCase()), res)
    );
  }
  return res;
}

const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const result = getText(container);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>I am a text with <strong>bold</strong> word</p>
  <p><strong>I am bold text with nested <em>italic</em> Word.</strong></p>
</div>
```

**Relevant Documentations:**

- [Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)
- [Node.parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode)
- [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
- [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1):

A version not all that different from the other two posted here, but with a different breakdown in responsibilities.

```js
const getTextNodes = (node, path = []) =>
  node .nodeType === 3
    ? {text: node .nodeValue, path}
    : [... node .childNodes] .flatMap ((child) => getTextNodes (child, [... path, node .tagName .toLowerCase()]))

const extract = (keep) => (html) =>
  [...new DOMParser () .parseFromString (html, 'text/html') .body .childNodes] 
    .flatMap (node => getTextNodes (node))
    .map (({text, path = []}) => ({text, format: [...new Set (path .filter (p => keep .includes (p)))]}))

const reformat = extract (["em", "strong"])

const strHTML = "<p>Hello World</p><p>I am a text with <strong>bold</strong> word</p><p><strong>I am bold text with nested <em>italic</em> Word.</strong></p>"

console .log (reformat (strHTML))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This goes through an intermediate format, which might be useful for other purposes:

```js
[
  {text: "Hello World", path: ["p"]},
  {text: "I am a text with ", path: ["p"]},
  {text: "bold", path: ["p", "strong"]},
  {text: " word", path: ["p"]},
  {text: "I am bold text with nested ", path: ["p", "strong"]},
  {text: "italic", path: ["p", "strong", "em"]},
  {text: " Word.", path: ["p", "strong"]}
]
```

While this looks similar to your final format, the `path` includes the entire tag history to the text node, and could be used for various purposes.  `getTextNodes` extracts this format from a given node.  Thus a `path` might look like `["div", "div", "div", "nav", "ol", "li", "a", "div", "div", "strong"]`, with repeated elements, and many non-formatting tags.

The final `map` call in `extract` simply filters this path into your configured collection of formatting tags.

While we can easily do this in a single pass, `getTextNodes` is itself a useful function we might use elsewhere in our system.